# Creating a nested table with ddply

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr

I'm having trouble generating a table with `plyr` and I hope you can help. If you run the code below you should get a table with proportions at the highest aggregate level of my data (i.e., the whole data set). However, I'd like to get the same table with proportions per item for each school. Thanks for any help. Also, if there's a better way to synthesize this with just `dplyr` I'm open to it. I'm trying to integrate some of these new packages into my workflow.

```
# load packages
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(xtable)
# generate fake Data
set.seed(500)
School <- rep(seq(1:20), 2)
District <- rep(c(rep("East", 10), rep("West", 10)), 2)
Score <- rnorm(40, 100, 15)
Student.ID <- sample(1:1000,8,replace=T)
items <- data.frame(replicate(10, sample(1:4, 40, replace=TRUE)))
items <- data.frame(lapply(items, factor, ordered=TRUE, 
levels=1:4, 
labels=c("Strongly disagree","Disagree",
"Agree","Strongly Agree")))
school.data <- data.frame(Student.ID, School, District, Score, items)
rm(items)
# code for table
items <- select(school.data, School, X1:X10) 
g <- items %>% 
    gather(Item, response, -School)
# This gives me the aggregate results for the entire data set
foo <- ddply(g, .(Item), function(x)  prop.table(table(x$response))) #I stupidly tried .(Item, School) to no avail
xtable(foo)
```

Comment: Try `prop.table(with(g, table(response, Item, School)), margin = 2)`, which gives a 4x10x20 array (responses, items, schools). You can use `as.data.fame` on the result for conversion if needed.

Comment: @lukeA: Thank you very much. This gets me close enough to what I need. I was over-thinking it in a disorganized way.

Comment: R universe is overwhelming sometimes - has its pros and cons. ;) I'll post it as an answer. Check it if you like, or wait for other answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
prop.table(with(g, table(response, Item, School)), margin = 2)
```

This gives a 4x10x20 array (responses, items, schools). You can use `as.data.fame` on the result for conversion if needed.

Comment: Wait: this works perfectly for what I asked, and is something I need to do as well. I just need to use a different function in conjunction with `with` and `g`. Thanks!

Comment: Or did you want something like `tabs <- with(g, table(response, Item, School)); for (x in 1:dim(tabs)[3]) tabs[,, x] <- prop.table(tabs[,, x], 2) * 100; tabs` - proportions per school? Well you got it anyway as it seems. ;)

Comment: If you have time (and I think this will add to the interpretive value of the answer). Can you do just explain what is going on with this piece of code: `tabs <- with(g, table(response, Item, School)); for (x in 1:dim(tabs)[3]) tabs[,, x] <- prop.table(tabs[,, x], 2) * 100; tabs.` It works beautifully, and I've adapted it to every situation I need, but I'd be lying if I said I understood what it meant in full.

Comment: Well, the `for` loop iterates over each school (= 3rd dimension of the `tabs` table array) and replaces the table (= absolute) values by the prop.table (= relative) values for just that one school.